# What the name of the vector orthogonal to the projection of A on B?

Tags: vectors

If the $\vec{b}$ is the **projection** of $\vec{a}$ on $\vec{y}$ then what is the name of the vector $\vec{x' x}$ that is normal to $\vec{b}$.

[image]

I want to name a function in my program that returns this vector and I can't think of the correct term.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958198/vector-projection-rejection-in-c

Comment: Thankyou.. However my problem was not the implementation, which is easy, but the naming. I wasn't aware of the term "rejection" before.

Answer (score 3):

The normal to the **projection** is the **rejection**

I found it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection#Vector_rejection)